# Not able to schedule refresh report on POWER BI for web

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I was able to refresh a power BI report using the desktop application. But when I am trying to schedule a refresh using the web application I am getting the following error.

[image]

I am getting data using the web source. I am using functions in the connection string. Is there a way I can schedule refresh in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size for datasets imported into the Power BI service is 1 GB and Power BI Service places a limit on the amount of uncompressed data that is processed during refresh to 10 GB.

If you still hit the above two limitations, you are not able to refresh dataset in Power BI Service. You can use DirectQuery/Live connection mode to connect to your data source instead, or purchase Power BI Premium license to solve this issue.

You can also try to solve the issue by creating a view of the table within the source database

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/report-server/scheduled-refresh